# Ternary operator in C vs C++

Tags: c++, c, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

There are a lot of differences between C and C++ and came to stuck on one of them 
The same code gives an error in C while just executes fine in C++ 
Please explain the reason

```
int main(void)
{
   int a=10,b;
   a>=5?b=100:b=200;
}
```

The above code gives an error in **C** stating **lvalue** required while the same code compiles fine in **C++**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at the operator precedence.

Without an explicit `()` your code behaves like

```
( a >= 5 ? b = 100 :  b ) = 200;
```

The result of a `?:` expression is not a *modifiable lvalue* <sup>[#]</sup> and hence we cannot *assign* any values to it.

Also, worthy to mention, as per the `c` syntax rule,

> assignment is never allowed to appear on the right hand side of a conditional operator

Relared Reference : [C precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

OTOH, In case of `c++`, well,

> the conditional operator has the same precedence as assignment.

and are grouped right-to-left, essentially making your code behave like

```
 a >= 5 ? (b = 100) : ( b = 200 );
```

So, your code works fine in case of `c++`

---

[ # ] -- As per chapter 6.5.15, footnote (12), `C99` standard,

> A conditional expression does not yield an lvalue.

Answer (score 7):

Because C and C++ aren't the same language, and you are ignoring the assignment implied by the ternary. I think you wanted

```
b = a>=5?100:200;
```

which should work in both C and C++.

Answer (score 6):

In C you can fix it with placing the expression within Parentheses so that while evaluating the assignment becomes valid.

```
int main(void)
{
   int a=10,b;
   a>=5?(b=100):(b=200);
}
```

The error is because you don't care about the operator precedence and order of evaluation.