# Why is this code involving the ternary operator getting an error in C, but not in C++?

Tags: c++, c

I get "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment" for "x=k" in C, but the code runs without an error in C++. I don't understand why C is giving me this error, while C++ doesn't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
    int j=10, k=50, x;
    j<k ? x=j : x=k; 
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

Comment: Because C and C++ are different languages

Comment: Well in general, C is not C++. For the C version, you would want `x = (j < k) ? j : k;`

Comment: why not just `x = j < k ? j : k; // ?`

Comment: @Rogue yes C and C++ are different, but sometimes the differences aren't obvious. Understanding those differences helps us all.

Comment: Because, in C++, `?:` has the same precedence as assignment operators, but in C, it has higher precedence.    So, in C++, `j<k ? x=j : x=k` is equivalent to `(j<k) ? (x=j) : (x=k)` but in C it is equivalent to `((j<k) ? (x=j) : x)=k`.   You can notionally fix by adding `()` liberally.   But, as written, your code only belongs in code obfuscation challenges, not in production code so would probably be better expressed as [assuming this reflects the intent] `x = (j < k) : j : k`

Comment: @MarkRansom I disagree, C++ is based on an ancient version of C and still supports some things. You really should treat them as different languages. Using current C++ guidelines should produce very different code from what "C" can do. All that the differences show us IS that they are different language and IMO should be treated as such.

Comment: dup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082682/4641116

Comment: @PepijnKramer they may be different languages but they share the same background, and 99% of the time the parts that they share work the same. I still assert that knowing those differences is useful.

Comment: It is useful C++ can still compile legacy code, but new C++ code should look remarkably different from new C code.  (RAII, STL containers i.o. malloc/free, new/delete, unique pointer ownership, references, exception safe programming techniques etc. etc.). So lets respectfully disagree then :) And yes part of my view comes from the fact I don't need to use those 2 languages at the same time.

Comment: Exact duplicate of: [Ternary operator in C vs C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337054/ternary-operator-in-c-vs-c)

Comment: @PepijnKramer *"C and C++ are different languages"* That's all that need to be said

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C, the ternary operator `?:` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.  So this:

```
j<k ? x=j : x=k;
```

Parses as this:

```
((j<k) ? (x=j) : x)=k;
```

This is an error in C because the result of the ternary operator is not an lvalue, i.e. it does not denote an object and so can't appear on the left side of an assignment.

C++ however has `?:` and `=` at the same precedence level, so it parses the expression like this:

```
j<k ? x=j : (x=k);
```

Which is why it works in C++.  And actually, C++ *does* allow the result of the ternary operator to be an lvalue, so something like this:

```
(j<k ? a : b ) = k;
```

Is legal in C++.

You'll need to add parenthesis to get the grouping you want:

```
j<k ? x=j : (x=k);
```

Or better yet:

```
x = j<k ? j : k;
```

Comment: Or just `x = min(j, k);`

Comment: This answer is missing the fact that `?:` has the same precedence as assignment operators in C++, but higher precedence in C.